# Cannot run flash live streming from other website on my website

Tags: jquery, html, flash

I am trying to use following live streaming on my website but it get connection error can i consume it on my website

Is it protect some how or i am making nay mistake in my code

[Link](http://www.dmi.ae/live.asp?lang=en&ChannelID=2) from where i want to consume live streaming

Example on [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/VjatJ/)

```
<object width="650" height="476" name="single1" id="single1" classid="clsid:D27CDB6E-AE6D-11cf-96B8-444553540000">
        <param value="http://statics.dubaimedia.ae/flv-player/player.swf" name="movie">
        <param value="true" name="allowfullscreen">
        <param value="always" name="allowscriptaccess">
        <param value="transparent" name="wmode">
        <param value="playlistfile=http://stream4.dmi.ae/live4/smil:smartdubaisport.smil/jwplayer.rss&amp;dock=false&amp;rtmp.subscribe=true&amp;autoplay=true" name="flashvars">
        <param value="true" name="autoplay">
        <embed width="650" height="476" autoplay="true" flashvars="playlistfile=http://stream4.dmi.ae/live4/smil:smartdubaisport.smil/jwplayer.rss&amp;dock=false&amp;rtmp.subscribe=true&amp;autoplay=true" wmode="transparent" allowfullscreen="true" allowscriptaccess="always" bgcolor="undefined" src="http://statics.dubaimedia.ae/flv-player/player.swf" name="single2" id="single2" type="application/x-shockwave-flash"></object>
```

Comment: It's most probably restricting streaming if the player is hosted on other domains.

Comment: I have the same feeling as i cant find anything wrong with the code path is correct. So it must be protecting it.

Answer (score 0):

It restricts streaming based on the URL of the page in which the player resides in. Proof:

- edit your `hosts` file and point domain `www.dmi.ae` to `127.0.0.1`
- save your html under your local web server and access it using `http://www.dmi.ae/...path to your html`
- the video will play

Comment: You can't do that, domain resolution through the `hosts` file only works for the machine you are on (client machine).